# Error in "npm start" command of angular seed cloning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, npm

I am getting the below error when i clone the angular seed from github and run the node server. I have cloned the angular seed to the existing project directory. I am not sure what is going wrong. But i am getting the below error. Kindly help

```
$ npm start

> StickyTodos@0.0.0 prestart C:\projects\StickyTodos
> npm install


> StickyTodos@0.0.0 postinstall C:\projects\StickyTodos
> bower install


> StickyTodos@0.0.0 start C:\projects\StickyTodos
> http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:883:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at net.js:1379:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:63:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:82:10)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! StickyTodos@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the StickyTodos@0.0.0 start script 'http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the StickyTodos package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls StickyTodos
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\projects\StickyTodos\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

The error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000` is explaining that something is already bound to port 8000.

As you are on Windows, running `netstat -a -b` in an elevated command prompt (Right click start button and press Command Prompt (Admin)) should show you what is already listening to port 8000.

Simply stop that process, or alternatively bind to a different port which is free.